# select search queries from url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here's what I have so far:

```
preg_match('/[q|p]=(.*?)&/',$url,$query);
```

The problem is that if there's a param that ends with a `q` or `p`, the it will include those:

```
&cap=queryhere
```

since `cap` ends with `p` it includes those, how can I only include search queries that come from q's and p's only. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to use regular expressions, php has built in functions to work with type of information, it is more accurate.

```
<?php

$url = "http://mysite.com/page.php?q=this is my query&a=123";

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($query, $opt);

print_r($opt);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [q] => this is my query
    [a] => 123
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your regex to `'/\W[q|p]=(.*)&/'`
Adding the \W to the front matches only if the preceding digit is not a word character (a-Z,0-9, or _).

Personally, I would just use `$_GET['p']` or `$_GET['q']`.

```
<?php
   if ( isset($_GET['p']) )
      $query = $_GET['p'];
?>
```

Comment: doesn't work for `word?q=query` the query is what I want to match. Thanks Westy for taking a shot at it!

Comment: $_GET doesn't work if it isn't coming from the browser's URL, he didn't specify though. If it is then yes I would agree.